# Trouble reading from file in Haskell

Tags: haskell

i am new to Haskell and i am having a hard time with reading text and numbers from a file. i am trying to make a program that reads a lot of numbers and text and compares them, and i would like to know how can i read them into a list , so it would be easier to compare them, i think...

let's say i have a file with the following content:

```
File 1:
  Bill 9176
  Tom 9183
  Steve 4353
```

and i want to read the name and the number into a list, how can i do that ?

---

When i try to compile this code,

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String

parseNameNumber :: Parser (String, Integer)
parseNameNumber = do
spaces
name <- many1 letter
space
number <- fmap read $ many1 digit
return (name, number)

parseFile :: String -> IO ()
parseFile = do
result <- parseFromFile (parseNameNumber `sepBy` newline)
case result of
Left err  -> print err
Right res -> print res
```

it gives me these errors:

```
Couldn't match type `IO ()' with `String -> IO ()'
Expected type: IO (Either a0 a1)
               -> (Either a0 a1 -> IO ()) -> String -> IO ()
  Actual type: IO (Either a0 a1)
               -> (Either a0 a1 -> IO ()) -> IO ()
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  result <- parseFromFile (parseNameNumber `sepBy` newline)
In the expression:
  do { result <- parseFromFile (parseNameNumber `sepBy` newline);
       case result of {
         Left err -> print err
         Right res -> print res } }
In an equation for `parseFile':
    parseFile
      = do { result <- parseFromFile (parseNameNumber `sepBy` newline);
             case result of {
               Left err -> print err
               Right res -> print res } }

file.hs:14:13:
Couldn't match expected type `IO (Either a0 a1)'
            with actual type `String
                              -> IO (Either ParseError [(String, Integer)])'
In the return type of a call of `parseFromFile'
Probable cause: `parseFromFile' is applied to too few arguments
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  result <- parseFromFile (parseNameNumber `sepBy` newline)
In the expression:
  do { result <- parseFromFile (parseNameNumber `sepBy` newline);
       case result of {
         Left err -> print err
         Right res -> print res } }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should start by learning some basic Haskell. E.g. read this book http://learnyouahaskell.com/

Comment: @RomanCheplyaka i know how to read with getContents, but what i don't know is how i can read the data into tupples

Comment: What have you tried?  If you can get the contents with `getContents`, how do you separate that into lines? (hint: type `:type lines` into GHCi).  Once you have each line, how do you convert that line into words? (hint: type `:type words` into GHCi).

Comment: The long error message is because you are missing the filename argument to `parseFromFile`. (There's a suggestion about that in the error message.)

Answer (score 4):

Look at your data.

```
"Bill 9176" :: String
```

Now back to your tuple

```
("Bill", 9176) :: (String, Int)
```

Now back to your data.  Sadly it isn't a tuple.  But with some pure functions it could be the type you desire.  Look down, back up.  Where are you?  You're in front a computer screen running vim in terminal.  What's the type of `read` ?

```
read :: Read a => a
```

Back at the `String`.  You can split the string with `words`.

```
words :: String -> [String]
```

Anything is possible when your functions are data and your data is functions.  I'm in a monad.

```
parseLine :: String -> (String, Int)
parseLine xs = (\(n:i:_) -> (n, read i)) (words xs)
```

Comment: "But it could become a tuple if it used pure functions" if you want to stick to the oldspice theme :)

Comment: So basically if i want to read a file and just not one tuple, how can i adapt this function?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like your problem is parsing, not reading the file. I favor the Haskell library called `Parsec` for parsing. It can be installed with `cabal install parsec`. Then

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String

parseNameNumber :: Parser (String, Integer)
parseNameNumber = do
  spaces
  name <- many1 letter
  space
  number <- fmap read $ many1 digit
  return (name, number)

parseFile :: String -> IO ()
parseFile s = do
  result <- parseFromFile (parseNameNumber `sepBy` newline) s
  case result of
    Left err  -> print err
    Right res -> print res
```

Of course this can be done by manipulating your strings with list operations and then applying `read`, but it's much less robust. Perhaps it's overkill, but I still will mention it as something that's worth learning.

Comment: i'm trying to compile your code, in order to try it out, but it gives me a lot of errors

Comment: @user3028943 Do you mind saying what those errors are? It compiles for me

Comment: i put it in a new answer :)

Comment: @jozefg i'm sorry but if i want read something from a file using these program, how can i do it ?

Comment: @dcarou The function that says `parseFile` takes a file and parses it.. the part of the conditional that says `Right res ->` is where you can use the parse result.

Comment: so if i wanted to read from a file named in.txt, my command would be "parseFile in.txt", correct ? @jozefg

Comment: @jozefg if i want to read this file to a list of tuples, instead of printing it out, how would i do that ?